# How to use str_replace in objects

Tags: php, laravel

I want to put comma after each category like this :
test , test 2 , test 3

```html
<p>
    @foreach($article->categories()->get() as $categoris)  
        {{$categoris->title}}
    @endforeach
</p>
```

I tried this :

```html
<p>
    @foreach($article->categories()->get() as $categoris)  
        {{str_replace(' ' , ',' , $categoris->title)}}
    @endforeach
</p>
```

but it didn't work like I want.
the output was :
test, test 2 test 3

Comment: What's the value of `$categoris->title`?

Comment: test test 2 test 3

Comment: What was in the categoris in each iteration?

Comment: I want to the output like this : test , test 2 , test 3

Comment: First of all, remove the `@`, so it can display errors (This is the error control operator). In all cases, this is html with embedded php, with shorthand everywhere, such a mess. Write it yourself, pure php, don't copy, use a template engine, this is the key to learn. Don't mix logic and templating.

Comment: @ThamerAlluqmani If `$categoris->title` is `test test 2 test 3`, how is `str_replace` supposed to know which spaces matter and which ones don't?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each element in `categories` is a single category, so you're joining the titles of them all, you should be able to do something like:

```php
    @php 
        implode(', ', $article->categories()->pluck('title')->toArray()) 
    @endphp
```